# Error mounting hard drive with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: mount

I have used my hard drive for months with three others computers with ubuntu 10.04 and another 12.10 and suddenly it stopped working. It doesn't want to mount and the error message says:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

How can I access my hard disk again?

Answer (score 0):

If the drive was NTFS (likely if you used it on a windows machine), you may want to follow the advice in the warning message. Connect the drive to a windows machine and use the `chkdik` utility as described.

Unfortunately, now may be the time to put your data backup strategy to the test (sometimes disks fail).

Answer (score 0):

OP says that the old machines were also Ubuntu.

Can you check that the drive still works on any of the old machines (or any other machine)? If it doesn't work on another machine, then you likely have a disk failure.